# How to Set alarm on due date Button?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to build notepad and I am finish up with all. Just I want to have alarm on Date picker button. I have used date picker button. So want alarm to be set on due date and we have notification popup. Please suggest from where I need to start. Thanks

```
    duedate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.duedate);

    duedatetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duedatetext);

            case R.id.duedate:

            final Calendar duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = duedate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = duedate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = duedate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            showDialog(DIALOG_DUE_DATE_ID);
```

I have set Date text in listview also in list item click layout. So Please help me to do so. Thanks.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) for a good overview of the AlarmManager, which you'll be using to set your alarm.